# Why does only part of my contact form come through >

Tags: php

My contact form seems to send only part of the info through.

I can't spot anything different in any part of the set up, but the systems sends neither the phone number nor the mobile number.

### In my form I have

```
<form method="POST" name="contactform" action="changeofaddressfour.php"> 
<p>
<label for='name'>Your Name:</label> <br>
<input type="text" name="name">
 </p>
 <p>
<label for='email'>Email Address:</label> <br>
<input type="text" name="email"> <br>
 </p>
 <p>
 <label for='phone'>Telephone Number:</label> <br>
 <input type="text" name="phone"> <br>
</p>
 <p>
<label for='mobile'>Mobile Number:</label> <br>
<input type="text" name="mobile"> <br>
 </p>
 <p>
<label for='message'>New Address:</label> <br>
<textarea name="message"></textarea>
 </p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
</form>
```

---

And in the other page I have

```
  <?php
  $errors = '';
  $myemail = 'antonylambert@c5d.co.uk';//<-----Put Your email address here.
  if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['message'])) {
   $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
    }
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email_address = $_POST['email'];
 $telephone_number = $_POST['phone'];
 $mobile_number = $_POST['mobile'];
   $message = $_POST['message'];
if (!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]        {2,3})$/i", $email_address)) {
   $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
 }
 if (empty($errors)) {
 $to = $myemail;
 $email_subject = "Change of Details: $name";
 $email_body = "You have received a new message. "."Here are the details:\n Name: $name      \n Email: $email_address \n Message \n $message";
$headers = "From: $myemail\n";
 $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
 //redirect to the 'ackofdetails' page
 header('Location: ackofdetailsfour.php');
exit();
 }
echo nl2br($errors); ?>
```

Comment: You don't include the variables `$telephone_number` and `$mobile_number` in your `$email_body`, therefore they don't show up in the e-mail.

Comment: Your Code is alright and the only reason you might not get them because those variables are not used in Body.

Comment: Do you mean like this ?

$email_subject = "Change of Details: $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message. "."Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n Email: $email_address \n phone: $telephone_number \n mobile: $mobile_number\n Message \n $message";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change 
`$email_body = "You have received a new message. "."Here are the details:\n Name: $name      \n Email: $email_address \n Message \n $message";`

to

`$email_body = "You have received a new message. "."Here are the details:\n Name: $name      \n Email: $email_address \n Telephone Number: $telephone_number \n Mobile Number:  $mobile_number \n Message \n $message";`

Comment: Thank you.  That's perfect.  I've googled for hours trying to find this.